# Tree structure parent element

Tags: html, css, list, tree

I have a piece of code to make Element 1 and 2 in Menu colorful on hover with CSS. What is the HTML code for 0. Element "VCM Panopto"(parent)? If i write child:0 it doesn't work
[image]

```html
div.o_tree.o_tree_root_visible.o_course_menu ul.o_tree_l0 li.active_parent ul.o_tree_l1 li:nth-Child(1) span.o_tree_link.o_tree_l1.o_tree_level_label_leaf.active, 
div.o_tree.o_tree_root_visible.o_course_menu ul.o_tree_l0 li.active_parent ul.o_tree_l1 li:nth-Child(1) span.o_tree_link.o_tree_l1.o_tree_level_label_leaf.focus,
div.o_tree.o_tree_root_visible.o_course_menu ul.o_tree_l0 li.active_parent ul.o_tree_l1 li:nth-Child(1) span.o_tree_link.o_tree_l1.o_tree_level_label_leaf:hover, 
div.o_tree.o_tree_root_visible.o_course_menu ul.o_tree_l0 li.active_parent ul.o_tree_l1 li:nth-Child(1) span.o_tree_link.o_tree_l1.o_tree_level_label_leaf a:hover
{
    background-color: #2f7ca6;     /* BLUE */
    /*color: #fff;*/
}

div.o_tree.o_tree_root_visible.o_course_menu ul.o_tree_l0 li.active_parent ul.o_tree_l1 li:nth-Child(2) span.o_tree_link.o_tree_l1.o_tree_level_label_leaf.active, 
div.o_tree.o_tree_root_visible.o_course_menu ul.o_tree_l0 li.active_parent ul.o_tree_l1 li:nth-Child(2) span.o_tree_link.o_tree_l1.o_tree_level_label_leaf.focus,
div.o_tree.o_tree_root_visible.o_course_menu ul.o_tree_l0 li.active_parent ul.o_tree_l1 li:nth-Child(2) span.o_tree_link.o_tree_l1.o_tree_level_label_leaf:hover, 
div.o_tree.o_tree_root_visible.o_course_menu ul.o_tree_l0 li.active_parent ul.o_tree_l1 li:nth-Child(2) span.o_tree_link.o_tree_l1.o_tree_level_label_leaf a:hover
{
    background-color: #b10058;     /* FUCHSIA */
    /*color: #fff;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code worked

```
 #dd102071742529541 > .o_tree_link:hover {
 background-color: green !important;
 }
```